# Change a pivot field based on another pivot field

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to change a pivot field based on another pivot field in second sheet, and I'm getting a 'Run time error 13 Type Mismatch' [Error 13 Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)
Sorry for not mentioning earlier data type is just a two letter string like FR, for france
Here's my code

```
Sheets(Sheet1).PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("country_iso")_
  =Sheets(Sheet2).PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("country_iso")
```

Comment: What type of value is returned by `"country_iso"` (text, number...)?

Comment: Are you trying to add the Field or modify what it returns?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know the datatypes involved... but without any more info, I would suggest adding Val(), if it is a number, or CStr(), if it is a string - around the value you're trying to assign:

```
Sheets(Sheet1).PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("country_iso")_
   =Val(Sheets(Sheet2).PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("country_iso"))
```

or

```
Sheets(Sheet1).PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("country_iso")_
   =CStr(Sheets(Sheet2).PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("country_iso"))
```